# Provider org.hibernate.envers.event.EnversIntegrator not a subtype error in CDI+JPA2.1+Restful

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, cdi, jpa-2.1

I am trying to call JPA from a rest web service. but it throws me

```
    org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.envers.event.EnversIntegrator not a subtype at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:170) at
    org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:136) at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204) at 
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101) at
    org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.AutoJAXRSInvoker.invoke(AutoJAXRSInvoker.java:68) at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor
```

I have used maven 4, JPA 2.1, CDI.

My code:
JPA part:

```
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("defaultMainUnit", null);
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    Persistence.generateSchema("defaultMainUnit", null);

    Query master Query = entityManager
            .createNamedQuery("master.findAll");
    List<Master > masterList = masterQuery.getResultList();
    for(Master  master : masterList){
        System.out.println("Master id: "+master .getMaster TrackingId());
    }
    entityManager.clear();
    entityManager.close();
```

persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="defaultMainUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <class>core.Master</class>
    <class>core.Child</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:defaultDB" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_statement"/>

        <!-- insert data using sql file -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="metadata"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="mcb-test-import.sql"/>


    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Restservice:

```
    package restcdi.rest;

    @Path("/")
    public class GreetREST {

    @Inject
    private EnglishGreet greet;

    @GET
    @Path("/greet")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String greet() {
    return greet.greet();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/master")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List master() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
CheckJPAProperties check = new CheckJPAProperties();
List masterList = check.runMe();
return masterList;
    }
    }
```

in the above code, runMe() returns all the masters in database using JPA code above. when i run the JPA code without a rest service in main it runs fine and returns everything. I am not sure what I am missing. I tried including the hibernate-envers dependency in pom.xml but it still throws the same error. 
please help.

ps: just in case this is needed i am including my applicationConfig

```
    package restcdi.rest;

    import java.util.Set;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

    @javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("rest")
    public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    resources.add(GreetREST.class);
    return resources;
    }
    }
```

Comment: My guess is there is an exception so AbstractInvoker.createFault is trying to generate related exception but it faces another compatibility issue. I would put a break point to AbstractInvoker.java line 170 and debug application, there at least you would be able to see given Throwable param which is real exception

Comment: so I kept going through the debugger and I noticed that it throws a org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException. my entity files run fine on a unit test. maybe i am missing something